# Can you add two spans to "link_to"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
    <a href="#"><span>Ineffable</span><span>Evanescent Life</span></a>
    <a href="#"><span>Chatoyant</span><span>Assemblage Love</span></a>
```

I have the code above, how do I make it into link_to and include both spans at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use link_to's block form:

```
<%= link_to "#" do %>
  <span>Ineffable</span><span>Evanescent Life</span>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "#" do %>
  <span>Chatoyant</span><span>Assemblage Love</span>
<% end %>
```